# How to append/ add to a Array of Arrays in Swift based on specified index? [ [String]]()

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I want to make a Array of Arrays for Strings `[[String]]()` and be able to specify by index which inner list i want to append to

I have a var declared as:
`var myList = [[String]]`

I ideally want it to be something like this : `[ ["a","b"], ["l","m"] ]` and have the ability to specify which inner list gets the new element/ letter via a index
I have tried :

```
myList[index].insert("c", at: index) //gives and error saying index out of range

myList[index].append("c") //gives and error saying index out of range

if myList[index].isEmpty {
myList[index].append("c")
}//gives and error saying index out of range
```

but whenever i try to add to it i get an index out of range error as shown above.

Comment: What is the value `index`? Is it greater than 1? You only have two items in the array, so if index is greater than 1 it will give you an index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is that since you initialize `myList` as an empty array (`var myList: [[String]] = []`), you cannot reference items at specific indexes.

You can make a method like this to make sure you aren't accessing non-existant indexes:

```
func addToNested(_ index: Int, _ item: String) {
    while index >= myList.count {
        myList.append([])
    }
    myList[index].append(item)
}
```

This way it will check to see that you have enough arrays nested inside `myList`. That way if you call the following:

```
addToNested(0, "a")
addToNested(1, "l")
addToNested(0, "b")
addToNested(1, "m")
```

`myList` will be equal to `[["a", "b"], ["l", "m"]]`

Comment: thanks but i dont really want to use a separate function

Comment: You can use whatever structure you want — doesn't this explain your issue? You can't reference an index that's outside of the range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size of the first dimension first. If you know exactly that you're gonna have `n` arrays, you can fix the problem by:

```swift
var myList: [[String]] = .init(repeating: [], count: n)
// which is shorthand for
var myList: [[String]] = Array(repeating: [], count: n)
// which can be rewritten like
var myList = Array<[[String]]>(repeating: [], count: n)
```

And you can use it like:

```swift
var myList: [[String]] = .init(repeating: [], count: 4)
myList[0].append("a")
myList[1].append("b")
myList[1].append("c")
myList[2].append(contentsOf: ["d", "f"])
myList[2].insert("e", at: 1)

print(myList)
> [["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], []]
```

<s>Or if you know that it's going to be NxM matrix, you can also do</s>

```swift
var myList: [[String]] = .init(repeating: .init(repeating: "", count: m), count: n)
```

Comment: @faezadshbfn thanks but the size of the inner arrays are not always the same, sometime some may have 1 or more

Comment: Well, first approach just defines the first dimension, for the second dimension you can manipulate them however you want. (I'll update the answer)